# My ISP does not redirect http to https for Squarespace hosted sites

Tags: http, https, isp

I recently discovered that my ISP does not load websites hosted on Squarespace, unless the URL includes the "https" prefix. If the URL just points to example.com or www.example.com, or http://www.example.com, the website doesn't load at all. (I just see a "This site can’t be reachedengineeringplastics.in took too long to respond. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" message in the browser, after a few minutes.)

But if the URL includes "https", as in https://example.com or https://www.example.com, everything works just fine.

I know that this issue is not related to the browser, device, LAN, or router, since I've been able to reproduce this issue across multiple browsers and devices, and on my office LAN, home WiFi, and neighbour's WiFi (all three of which use the same ISP). All the sites I tested work normally on other ISPs, and I should also mention that websites NOT hosted on Squarespace load fine on my ISP with or without the https prefix.

The ISP in question is BSNL in India. I also tried changing to Google DNS (8.8.8.8) but that did not solve the problem either. Meanwhile BSNL claims it's not their fault, and Squarespace says it's probably an ISP issue.

How can I troubleshoot and determine where the issue is? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Here is the list of websites I tested: blog.lyft.com slowtravelmagazine.com newinc.org aplusi.com darrenbooth.com

None of these work on my ISP without the https prefix.

Here are the devices I tried on: 1. Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit Version 1903 (2) Intel Core i3 6098 3.60 GHz

Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit Version 1903 (2) Intel Core i5 2310 2.9 GHz

Windows 10 Home 64 Bit Version 1903 Intel Core i5 2.67 GHz

Xiamo Note 7 Pro Android v9.0 Build 0.3.12.0.PFHINXM

Samsung A320F Android 8.0.0 Build R16NW

Here are the results for the trace route test to blog.lyft.com:

[Port 80](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dPjTS-CbZeLtp8KSWOHApzOsNA9Ngty4VgkMQcHX4JI)
[Port 443](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wtQbisGl_TrLW_8RK-aYj96yKlYYL9Lqs7v_B-OaE8Y)
[ICMP](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11_pxVTQEXKS83rVTkOwh6r7ve19OSauHZ-FGVOkfgP8)

Comment: It would be interesting to see a packet trace of an attempted HTTP connection to Squarespace including both TCP port 80 and ICMP. It would also be nice to see a working connection to port 443 on the same Squarespace site to compare it to.

Comment: Hello, Spiff. Thank you for the suggestion. I've edited the post to include the results of the trace route tests. Looks like port 80 is blocked. Any ideas on what I can do about it?

Comment: It sounds like an ISP has botched up transparent caching or something Like that, but could it be something in your router?  A workaround could be to use a VPN.

Comment: Thank you, @davidgo. I manage a Squarespace hosted site, and my concern is that visitors using this ISP who type in the naked URL of my site into their browser will not be able to access the site. This is actually a really popular ISP in this region, so that's quite a sizeable number of people.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Squarespace SSL setting (Settings / Advanced / SSL) is set to Secure (Preferred) instead of Insecure.